# ubuntu kernel devel: what's the equivalent of "kernel-devel" and "kernel_debuginfo" from rhel?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

On rhel, I can install

```
kernel-devel
kernel-debuginfo
kernel-debuginfo-common
```

To enable systemtap scripts. But on ubuntu, I don't find equivalent packages. I searched stack over flow and some packages like kernel-headers-`uname -r` but after installation, systemtap doesn't work.

So how to enable it?

Comment: SO is for programming questions. Try AskUbuntu.com.

Comment: This is what you're looking for http://askubuntu.com/questions/320288/what-is-the-linux-kernel-devel-equivalent-in-12-04-2-lts-3-5-0